# How to watch for form submit event in Rails with Turbolinks?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I want to watch for the submit event on a form in a Rails app with Turbolinks. I've come up with the following:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(e) {
  var arrangeForm;
  arrangeForm = document.querySelector('#arrange-dust-form');
  if (arrangeForm) {
    return arrangeForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      // do stuff on submit...
    });
  }
});
```

This works, but the part about `if (arrangeForm)` seems awkward. But if I don't check for the form's existence, I get an error when navigating to other pages of my site, since it tries to set the listener on an element that doesn't exist.

Is there a 'right' or 'official' way to do this where I don't have to check for the existence of the form on every `turbolinks:load` event? Is there a more applicable node I should be attaching the event to?

Answer (score 0):

The Rails way for any specific js that is only to be run on one page and not included app-wide would be to use content_for on the view page you're interested in:

```
    <% content_for :myjava do %>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
        document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(e) {
          var arrangeForm;
          arrangeForm = document.querySelector('#arrange-dust-form');
        if (arrangeForm) {
        return arrangeForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
          // do stuff on submit...
        });
       }
      });
     </script>
  <% end %>
```

And then in your layouts/application.html.erb file you'd yield to at the end of  your body tag  like:

```
<body>
  #whatever layout view code
  <%= yield :myjava %>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

### A Basic Solution

The [Turbolinks Readme](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#observing-navigation-events) recommends using event delegation to handle events:

> When possible, avoid using the turbolinks:load event to add other event listeners directly to elements on the page body. Instead, consider using event delegation to register event listeners once on document or window.

For example:

```
window.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
  if (event.target.id === '#arrange-dust-form') {
    // do stuff on submit…
  }
})
```

This makes our event handler more flexible since it does not require a `turbolinks:load` event in order to work. If your `#arrange-dust-form` was added dynamically after `turbolinks:load`, or even if you removed Turbolinks altogether, this code would still work.

### Creating a Basic Event Delegation System

The above solution is fine, but checking the event target each time you want to handle an event is laborious. It would be nicer if we only had to state the name of the event, the event handler, and a CSS selector to restrict when the handler is called. jQuery has a nice API for this:

```
$(window).on('submit', '#arrange-dust-form', function (event) {
  // do stuff on submit…
})
```

But if you're not using jQuery, or don't wish to, we can recreate a basic version:

```
;(function () {
  var eventTypes = [
    'click', 'mouseover', 'mouseout', 'mousedown',
    'mouseup', 'mouseenter', 'mouseleave', 'mousemove',
    'keydown', 'keyup', 'submit', 'change', 'contextmenu',
    'dblclick', 'input', 'focusin', 'focusout'
  ]

  // Build structure for storing event handlers
  var handlers = eventTypes.reduce(function (obj, eventType) {
    obj[eventType] = {}
    return obj
  }, {})

  // Add listeners for each event
  eventTypes.forEach(function (eventType) {
    window.addEventListener(eventType, function (event) {
      var handlersForEvent = handlers[eventType]

      for (var selector in handlersForEvent) {
        if (event.target.matches(selector)) {
          callHandlers(handlersForEvent[selector], event)
        }
      }
    })
  })

  function callHandlers (eventHandlers, event) {
    eventHandlers.forEach(function (handler) {
      handler.call(null, event)
    })
  }

  window.App = {
    addEventListener: function (eventType, selector, handler) {
      (handlers[eventType][selector] = handlers[eventType][selector] || [])
        .push(handler)
    }
  }
})()

// Usage
App.addEventListener('submit', '#arrange-dust-form', function (event) {
  // do stuff on submit…
})
```

A brief rundown of what this does. First, it creates an object for storing event handlers for every event type. Then it adds an event listener for each event type. This listener fetches the handlers that match the event type, loops over the selectors, and if the event target matches the selector, the handlers are called. `App.addEventListener` gets the array of handlers for the given event type and selector (or creates an array if one does not exist) and pushes the handler on to that array. In this system multiple handlers can be added for a given event type / selector.

A couple of caveats: 1. `Element.matches` is not supported in IE, so you may want to [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches#Polyfill) or add a wrapping function to support this. 2. This does not add a method of removing event listeners, so this is something you may wish to add.

Hope that helps.